# How to call a component from a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm learning React Native and I got in an issue when I used `TouchableOpacity`.

I have in App.js component productHandler() method. 
I want `onPress`(when you click on Read More) to call **Product** component and to display it on the screen, but doesn't work.

When I click on Read More nothing happens.

```
class App extends Component {
  productHandler = () => {
    return <Product />;
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={style.header}>
        <View style={style.touchableButtonContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={style.touchableButton}
            onPress={this.productHandler}
          >
            <Text style={style.fontText}>Read More</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <Text>This is just a text</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the Product.js

```
class Product extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Product page</Text>
        <Text>Product page</Text>
        <Text>Product page</Text>
        <Text>Product page</Text>
        <Text>Product page</Text>
        <Text>Product page</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I learn in sandbox so this little code is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-20sh7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are not telling react where to render that component. The better way would be handle state and render based on the condition :

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    isActive: false
  };
  productHandler = () => {
    this.setState({ isActive: !this.state.isActive });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={style.header}>
        <View style={style.touchableButtonContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={style.touchableButton}
            onPress={this.productHandler}
          >
            <Text style={style.fontText}>
              {this.state.isActive ? "Hide" : "Read More"}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        {this.state.isActive && <Product />}
        {!this.state.isActive && <Text>This is just a text</Text>}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-oln9t

Comment: My friend, I want to show only the Product component on the page, not the App, too.

Comment: Its conditional statement you can render wherever you want. Add more context about your problem. From this question, I infer this only

Comment: There is no other problem my friend. When I click in Read More, I want to see on the page only the text that is inside Product component. I don't want to see the text from App.js

Comment: I have updated the code check again. this is what u want??

Comment: If it's just a single condition then it's fine to implement this code. If you want to render more views make sure you read here more: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation

Answer (score 1):

You can't return a component from a click handler like that. Where would you even expect it to display in that case?

Instead, you need to keep some state, change that state on click, and then conditionally render the `Product` component based on that state.

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    this.state = { showingProduct: false }
    super()
  }

  productHandler = () => {
    this.setState({ showingProduct: true })
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={style.header}>
        <View style={style.touchableButtonContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={style.touchableButton}
            onPress={this.productHandler}
          >
            <Text style={style.fontText}>Read More</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

          { this.state.showingProduct && <Product /> }

        </View>
        <Text>This is just a text</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: My friend, I want to show only the Product component on the page, not the App, too.

Comment: In that case, you should probably read through the docs here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation